# How to track dependencies of Java Function Apps

Tags: java, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I setup some dependency tracking for a Azure Function App implemented with Java. Therefore I added `applicationinsights-core` as dependency, see [Add the Application Insights SDK for Java to your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-get-started?tabs=maven#add-the-application-insights-sdk-for-java-to-your-project).

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>applicationinsights-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

To create a `dependencies` entry, I use an instance of `TelemetryClient`.

```java
// call an external service, e.g. ADLS file upload..
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
uploadFile();
long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

// void trackDependency(String dependencyName, String commandName, Duration duration, boolean success)
new TelemetryClient().trackDependency(
  "ADLS", "upload file", new Duration(elapsed), true);
```

The resulting `dependencies` entry looks strange. It misses the `cloud_RoleName`, which usually identifies the creator of the entry. In addition, the `commandName` is passed as `data` property and there seems no way to set the `type` property of the entry.

While I found no dedicated Java Function App documentation for dependency tracking, the general Java documentation recommends to use the `applicationinsights-agent` additionally (see [Java codeless application monitoring Azure Monitor Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent)). The agent handles the telemetry of `applicationinsights-core` (see [Supported custom telemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent#supported-custom-telemetry)). But it isn't obvious to me, how to setup the agent for Azure Function App.

How can I setup the `cloud_RoleName`?
Is there a way to set `dependencies`'s `type` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using just `applicationinsights-core`.

- The `cloud_RoleName` can be taken from the environment variable `WEBSITE_SITE_NAME`.
- The `type` can be configured via a setter of `RemoteDependencyTelemetry`.

```
// create depedencies entry
createTelemetryClient().trackDependency(
  buildTelemetry("ADSL", "upload file", "custom context", successful, elapsed));
// ..

private TelemetryClient createTelemetryClient() {
  TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.getActive();
  configuration.setRoleName(System.getenv("WEBSITE_SITE_NAME"));
  return new TelemetryClient(configuration);
}

private RemoteDependencyTelemetry buildTelemetry(String type,
                                                 String name,
                                                 String data,
                                                 boolean successful,
                                                 long elapsed) {
    RemoteDependencyTelemetry telemetry = new RemoteDependencyTelemetry(
        name,
        data,
        new Duration(elapsed),
        successful);
    telemetry.setType(type);
    return telemetry;
}
```